# Redirection with a header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes

I use node js and express js. I want to make sure that if app.get is without a token parameter, then upload an html file with js that will pass the token. And if the token was passed, then show another html file.

But I do not know how to make a redirect from the client with the transfer of a header with a token

***Server:***

```
app.get("/admin-cp/:page", function (req, res) {
    const idToken = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!idToken)
    {

        return res.sendFile(path.join(initial_path, "admin-cp/loader.html"));
        //return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized")
    } 

    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || "";
    
    admin
        .auth()
        .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true  )
        .then((userData) => {
            console.log("Logged in:", userData.email)
            console.log('Авторизован. Доступ в админ панель открыт')


            admin
            .auth()
            .verifyIdToken(idToken)
            .then((claims) => 
            {  
                if (claims.admin === true) 
                {    
                    console.log('Зашёл с правами администратора', req.params.page);
                    if (req.params.page === 'analytics')
                    {
                        console.log("Open analytics");
                        res.sendFile(path.join(initial_path, "admin-cp/main-admin_cp.html"));
                        //res.render(path.join(initial_path, "admin-cp/main-admin_cp.html"));
                        //res.redirect('/admin-cp/home');
                    }
                } 
                else if (claims.admin === false)
                {
                    console.log('Зашёл без прав администратора');
                    //res.sendFile(path.join(initial_path, "admin-cp/global_not_permission.html"));
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
            });
            
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Не авторизован. Ошибка', error, ' отсутвует userData')
            res.redirect("/login");
        });

});
```

I tried to do with "fetch":

```
const res = await fetch('/admin-cp/analytics',  { headers: { authorization: idToken },  redirect: 'follow' })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.redirected) {
        document.location = res.url;
    }
  })
```

But after all the actions res.sendFile is not updated

help with any advice. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events goes like this.

1. You make a `fetch` request, including an `authorization` header, to the URL
2. The server responds with a redirect
3. The browser follows the redirect and makes a `fetch` request to the new URL (I've no idea if it include the `authorization` header again here)
4. The server responds with something which you mostly ignore
5. You read the URL that `fetch` was redirected to
6. You assign that URL to `document.location` causing the browser to make a **new** `GET` request to that URL (definitely **without** an `authorization` header).
7. The server side code sends `res.sendFile(path.join(initial_path, "admin-cp/loader.html"))` because there is no `authorization` header.

You can't make the browser navigate and include an `authorization` header.

If you want to do authentication while navigating: Use cookies instead.

Comment: I followed this advice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852831/how-to-get-a-firebase-idtoken-on-the-server/71852870#71852870

Comment: @NightNickname — And that advice is fine if you are using Ajax … but you are navigating to a whole new page.